# What is the difference between -fx-padding and -fx-label-padding in JavaFX CSS?

Tags: css, javafx

In JavaFX CSS, a `Label` seems to have 2 CSS padding properties.

[`Label`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#label) has all properties of [`Labeled`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled), and under that we have `-fx-label-padding`.

However, [`Labeled`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled) also has all properties of [`Control`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#control), which has all properties of [`Region`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region). Under that we find `-fx-padding`.

To me, those two properties seem to do the exact same thing. Can someone explain the difference between them, why might we need 2, and when to prefer one to another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-fx-label-padding` is especially used for `RadioButton` and `CheckBox`.

Here is a little MCVE that demonstrates the aim of this :

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

   /*
    * (non-Javadoc)
    * @see javafx.application.Application#start(javafx.stage.Stage)
    */
   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
      BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
      root.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("MyPadding.css").toExternalForm());
      Line line1 = new Line(-1, 1, 1, -1);
      Line line2 = new Line(-1, -1, 1, 1);

      HBox hb = new HBox(20.0);
      // Labels
      VBox vbLabels = new VBox(10.0);
      Label label = new Label("Hello no padding");
      label.setGraphic(Shape.union(line1, line2));
      label.getStyleClass().add("no-padding");
      Label label1 = new Label("Hello padding");
      label1.setGraphic(Shape.union(line1, line2));
      label1.getStyleClass().add("only-padding");
      Label label2 = new Label("Hello label-padding");
      label2.setGraphic(Shape.union(line1, line2));
      label2.getStyleClass().add("only-label-padding");
      Label label3 = new Label("Hello both paddings");
      label3.setGraphic(Shape.union(line1, line2));
      label3.getStyleClass().add("both-padding");
      vbLabels.getChildren().addAll(label, label1, label2, label3);

      // Radio buttons
      VBox vbRadios = new VBox(10.0);
      RadioButton radio = new RadioButton("Radio no padding");
      radio.getStyleClass().add("no-padding");
      RadioButton radio1 = new RadioButton("Radio only padding");
      radio1.getStyleClass().add("only-padding");
      RadioButton radio2 = new RadioButton("Radio label-padding");
      radio2.getStyleClass().add("only-label-padding");
      RadioButton radio3 = new RadioButton("Radio both paddings");
      radio3.getStyleClass().add("both-padding");
      vbRadios.getChildren().addAll(radio, radio1, radio2, radio3);

      // Checkboxes
      // Due to the bug (found in https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089059) it is not really demonstrative.
      VBox vbChecks = new VBox(10.0);
      CheckBox check = new CheckBox("My Check 0");
      check.getStyleClass().add("no-padding");
      CheckBox check1 = new CheckBox("My Check 1");
      check1.getStyleClass().add("only-padding");
      CheckBox check2 = new CheckBox("My Check 2");
      check2.getStyleClass().add("only-label-padding");
      CheckBox check3 = new CheckBox("My Check 3");
      check3.getStyleClass().add("both-padding");
      vbChecks.getChildren().addAll(check, check1, check2, check3);

      hb.getChildren().addAll(vbLabels, vbRadios, vbChecks);
      root.setCenter(hb);
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600.0, 500.0);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }

}
```

And the CSS file called MyPadding.css :

```
.no-padding {
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-label-padding: 0 0 0 0;
    -fx-padding : 0 0 0 0;
}

.only-padding {
    -fx-border-color : red;
    -fx-label-padding: 0 0 0 0em;
    -fx-padding : 0 0 0 2em;
}

.only-label-padding {
    -fx-border-color: blue;
    -fx-label-padding: 0 0 0 2em;
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 0em;
}

.both-padding {
    -fx-border-color: green;
    -fx-label-padding: 0 0 0 2em;
    -fx-padding : 0 0 0 2em;
}
```

That result in :

[image]

**Observation**

The checkboxes are displayed weirdly with Java 8 (because of this [known defect](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089059)).

`RadioButton` example shows that `-fx-label-padding` enables the user to set padding between the radio and the text while `-fx-padding` set padding to all the component.

`-fx-label-padding` and `-fx-padding` are added each other for `Label`.

I believed it was also used for adding a padding between the text and the graphic of a `Label` but apparently not.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. With examples it's very clear.

Answer (score 2):

From [the javadoc of the `Labeled.labelPadding` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#labelPaddingProperty):

> The padding around the `Labeled`'s text and graphic content. [...] Subclasses may add nodes outside this padding and inside the `Labeled`'s `padding`.

For `Label` both `Region.padding` and `Labeled.labelPadding` are simply added together. For different subclasses of `Labeled` there are differences though. E.g. `RadioButton` and `CheckButton` add this between the graphic/text and the mark